# jQuery handling of MS Word text pastes into html textarea

Tags: jquery, ms-word

I have a jQuery DIV with a texarea that gets pushed to a db.  The issue is, when a user pastes MS Word text containing quotes, they are converted to em-dashes.  As much I would love to ban M$ Anything, my users insist on formatting their uploads in Word, and copying-n-pasting in my textarea.  When I alert() the output, all the Word quotes are em-dashes.  This is a big problem because I have to support em-dashes, but outputting something like

--Hi!---- when it should be "Hi!" -- is really pissing me off, because I can't get at the underlying code M$ is using so I can change it. (where '--' == —)

The textarea transmits just fine when manually inputting ASCII; only pastes from M$hit Word screws it up.

I am using Mac OSX Snow Leopard uploading to a Linux server.

Has anyone encounter this issue and if so, what is the solution?

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a system with full setup to help you try out now, but I had a similar problem albeit with the apostrophe(') notation. I just did a string replace with the ASCII code to a code that I used as a marker, say 0xFF in HEX, then I stored it.

Subsequently, when you parse the file, replace the 0xFF back with whatever you want it to replace. Hope it helps :)